# Query related work items

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

In TFS, some of work items are assigned. For those tasks test cases work items created and linked to the appropriate tasks.

> I want to get the list of test cases linked for a particular task. How to write query to get it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use link query to get that:

```
SELECT [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State] 
FROM WorkItemLinks 
WHERE ([Source].[System.TeamProject] = @project  AND  
[Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Test Case') And 
([System.Links.LinkType] <> '') And ([Target].[System.Id] = @taskId) 
ORDER BY [System.Id] mode(MayContain)
```

Here's the code to run it:

```
var tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection("http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection");
var store = tpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

var queryContext = new Dictionary<string, string>();
queryContext.Add("project", "<team project name>");
queryContext.Add("taskId", "<task ID you are interested in>");

var query = new Query(store, "<WIQL query text>", queryContext);
var result = query.RunLinkQuery();
```